# Archived app has a no icon in organizer

Tags: xcode, icons, archive, organizer

Hello everyone I'm just about to submit my app and i have archived it but in the organizer the app icon shows up as blank for some reason. I have received no error messages and i have tried making another app with an icon and test if it has an icon in the organizer archaize but still the app icon shows up as blank. Anyone know the problem here? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The selected answer here worked for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601484/why-xcode-4-3-2-shows-white-icon-when-archived

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you imported iTunesArtwork.png into your project? If you haven't, do so, and make sure that you have the .png extension at the end.

Comment: Yes, I have added the 512 by 512 file into by Xcode project by dragging the file into the supporting files section. I have archived it again but still no icon picture. Do i need to tell Xcode somewhere to use the iTunesArtwork.png file for my app icon manually, or is it supposed to use it automatically? Also, I just dragged the file into supporting files. Does tat count as import? And did i put it in the right place? Thanks.

Comment: That should have been fine, and yes it should have been automatic. When you dragged it in was the "Add to Target" checkbox selected?

Comment: Yes, it was checked. still, no icon when I archive it and check it using organizer. What if I just submit the app to apple? The icon shows up fine when I run it on an iPod.

Comment: To be honest I really don't think it matters, I've run into that problem before, as well as read several posts about it, and I have to say it bugs me. However, it doesn't seem to make a difference if you include that graphic. Apple has accepted two of my apps when that icon wasn't showing up, as well as several of my friends apps with the same problem.

Comment: In addition, I see that you are new to Stack Overflow, (Welcome!) just a heads up about how things works here so your use of this website can be smooth. In the future, when you ask a question and you feel like one of the answers really helps you, mark it as correct by selecting the checkmark next to the post.

Answer (score 0):

Adding iTunesWork.png in my case did not help.  Maybe todays version of XCode which is 5  has different way to do it.

What i did is updated the projects .plist with the ff value:

Icon files (iOS 5)

- Primary Icon

  - Item 6    ----------   **MyArchiveIconHere.png**