# Why Xcode 4.3.2 shows white icon when archived?

Tags: ios, upload, app-store, xcode4.3

When i archived my app to upload to app store, app icon is being white. But in Xcode 4.2 everything is ok. In Xcode 4.3.2 app icon changes into white after archiving it. Xcode allows to upload to app store without any warning and error. Uploading is finished and waiting for review. I want to know, if Apple will reject my app for this?

Comment: Will Apple reject your app: No.

Comment: I think it's a bug in Xcode 4.3.2. [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800761/xcode-4-3-missing-icons-for-ios-apps-in-organizers-archives) is a same question.

Comment: BTW, you __should NOT__ add iTunesArtwork in your info.plist's CFBundleIconFiles, though it'll show the icon in organizer's archives.

Comment: Duplicated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800761/xcode-4-3-missing-icons-for-ios-apps-in-organizers-archives and you will find the answer (use "xcode-select -switch ...")

Comment: i have the same problem. didn't even try to solve it yet :) but application (update) normally passed validation and is in app store with correct icons

Comment: yes, me too. normally passed and validation with correct icons after uploading. Thanks for answering. :)

Comment: Thanks. that duplicated question fixed my problem. :)

Comment: same issue is in `Xcode 4.5 DP` also

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I fixed with RMeijs answer in [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800761/xcode-4-3-missing-icons-for-ios-apps-in-organizers-archives)

The way is open terminal and type following code.

```
xcode-select -print-path

/Developer

sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

after that restart XCodes,All icons in Organizer are fine.

That answer from RMeijs.

I wrote this answer for easily to find.

Comment: Yes this fixed it for me. I updated to Xcode 4.6.3 and I keep each version in its own directory so I used this: `/Applications/Xcode_4.6.3/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer`

Answer (score 0):

Include in the info.plist for the key "Icon File" the value "Icon.png". Do not forget to also include the image in the container.