# White iCon when archive in XCode5

Tags: ios, icons, app-store, xcode-organizer

I am getting suprised when archive my project to upload to `appstore`.

However previous projects archived are showing correct iCon.

When is test with Simulator and Physical devices , iCon is correct.

That is happening only this project. I also added all of necessary `iCon` for this project.

[image]

How can i fix it?

Comment: here is a same question that might help you.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601484/why-xcode-4-3-2-shows-white-icon-when-archived

Comment: :D that question is mine bro. I asked when with XCode 4. Now is with XCode5.

Comment: And also validation is passed without any messages. Should i upload it  bro?

Comment: you should take more time and fix it before uploading. if it still stays same after upload you need to do ot then better find solution now..thats my advise..there wont be any problem for uploading with this...good luck bro...